# Chart JS distance between bar stacked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I have created bar stacked graph in chart JS for maintaining All the shifts month wise Regular shifts, Annual Leave, Sick etc..., which is working fine.

Now as you can see the image its not showing proper data and distance between data-set, Can anyone help me to fix it? Check my java script code.

```
<script>
var MONTHS = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", 'Aug']
var barChartData = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", 'Aug'],
       datasets: [{label: 'Reg',backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,data: [4914, 4515, 5064, 4873, 5146, 5045, 5192, 5349]},
                  { label: 'AL',    backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,data: [0, 151, 122, 242, 99, 213, 295, 877]},
                  { label: 'SICK',backgroundColor: window.chartColors.green,data: [36, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0]}
        ]
};
window.onload = function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: barChartData,
        options: {
            title: {    display: true,text: "Chart.js Bar Chart - Stacked"},
               tooltips: {  mode: 'index',  intersect: false},
               responsive: true,
               scales: {xAxes: [{stacked: true}],yAxes: [{stacked: true,    type: 'linear',position: 'left'}]
            }
        }
    });
};
document.getElementById('randomizeData').addEventListener('click', function() {
    barChartData.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
        dataset.data = dataset.data.map(function() {    return randomScalingFactor();});
    });
    window.myBar.update();
});
// Define a plugin to provide data labels
Chart.plugins.register({
    afterDatasetsDraw: function(chartInstance, easing) {
        // To only draw at the end of animation, check for easing === 1
        var ctx = chartInstance.chart.ctx;
        chartInstance.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
            var meta = chartInstance.getDatasetMeta(i);
            if (!meta.hidden) {
                meta.data.forEach(function(element, index) {
                    // Draw the text in black, with the specified font
                    // Just naively convert to string for now
                    var dataString = dataset.data[index].toString();
                    // Make sure alignment settings are correct
                    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
                    var padding = 5;
                    var position = element.tooltipPosition();
                    ctx.fillText(dataString, position.x, position.y - (fontSize / 2) - padding);
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Looks fine to me. what do you mean by "not showing proper data and distance between data-set"?

Comment: Can't able to read data label properly, can u see distance between red,blue and green is very less on Jan, Feb etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the y-axis step size to 100 or something appropriate.. like this

```
<script>
var MONTHS = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", 'Aug']
var barChartData = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", 'Aug'],
       datasets: [{label: 'Reg',backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,data: [4914, 4515, 5064, 4873, 5146, 5045, 5192, 5349]},
                  { label: 'AL',    backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,data: [0, 151, 122, 242, 99, 213, 295, 877]},
                  { label: 'SICK',backgroundColor: window.chartColors.green,data: [36, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0]}
        ]
};
window.onload = function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: barChartData,
        options: {
            title: {    display: true,text: "Chart.js Bar Chart - Stacked"},
               tooltips: {  mode: 'index',  intersect: false},
               responsive: true,
               scales: {xAxes: [{stacked: true}],yAxes: [{stacked: true,    type: 'linear',position: 'left', ticks: { beginAtZero:true, stepSize: 10 }}]
            }
        }
    });
};
document.getElementById('randomizeData').addEventListener('click', function() {
    barChartData.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
        dataset.data = dataset.data.map(function() {    return randomScalingFactor();});
    });
    window.myBar.update();
});
// Define a plugin to provide data labels
Chart.plugins.register({
    afterDatasetsDraw: function(chartInstance, easing) {
        // To only draw at the end of animation, check for easing === 1
        var ctx = chartInstance.chart.ctx;
        chartInstance.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
            var meta = chartInstance.getDatasetMeta(i);
            if (!meta.hidden) {
                meta.data.forEach(function(element, index) {
                    // Draw the text in black, with the specified font
                    // Just naively convert to string for now
                    var dataString = dataset.data[index].toString();
                    // Make sure alignment settings are correct
                    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
                    var padding = 5;
                    var position = element.tooltipPosition();
                    ctx.fillText(dataString, position.x, position.y - (fontSize / 2) - padding);
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```